# Trying to remove the first row in python fails?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Hi I have some data in csv format.

I have some very simple code that is just meant to remove the first row:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("mydata.csv")
data = data.drop(data.columns[[0]],axis=0)
data.to_csv("mydata2.csv")
```

However when run, I receieve this error:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:/Users/george/Desktop/testing/output/PIVOTING.py", line 1
DtypeWarning: Columns (6) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/george/Desktop/testing/output/PIVOTING.py", line 5, in <module>
    data = data.drop(data.columns[[0]],axis=0)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3697, in drop
    errors=errors)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3111, in drop
    obj = obj._drop_axis(labels, axis, level=level, errors=errors)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3143, in _drop_axis
    new_axis = axis.drop(labels, errors=errors)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 4404, in drop
    '{} not found in axis'.format(labels[mask]))
KeyError: "['C'] not found in axis"
```

Comment: why don't you use the `skiprows` argument of pandas `read_csv`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, pandas `read_csv` accept `skiprows` to help achieve exatly that task, as covered extensively [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20637439/skip-rows-during-csv-import-pandas)

Comment: Okay, thanks, any idea why what I tried didn't work though?

Comment: IMO it's because you are passing to the `drop` function the first column and not the first row index.
I guess this should work `data.drop(data.index.values[0],axis=0)`