# How to read csv file skipping the description (present over several lines) into a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have several csv files. Each csv file is present with its description spanning across several rows (15 rows in few files, 100 rows in few other etc.). I want to read the csv files into dataframes. I tried to use pandas.DataFrame('file1.csv') for reading data into dataframe. How ever, I am getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "snowdepthData.py", line 5, in <module>
    depthDF = pd.DataFrame('Alaska_SD_Sep2019toOct2020.csv')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 485, in __init__
    raise ValueError("DataFrame constructor not properly called!")
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

Is there any way, I can skip reading the description and convert data into dataframe.

Thankyou.

Comment: Does this answer your question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20637439/skip-rows-during-csv-import-pandas

Comment: attach a reference of your file

Comment: @Shijith Following is the link for reference/sample data. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MxJDErUDCd-8ElwvIrE6V6DE78IhXlr1yfh4VNAp9UM/edit#gid=666820361

Comment: @RishabhKumar I have different files with different number of rows to be skipped. I am unsure about how to address it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those lines seem to begin with `#`, so you can probably use the [`comment`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) parameter:

> **comment** str, optional
>
> Indicates remainder of line should not be parsed. If found at the beginning of a line, the line will be ignored altogether.
> This parameter must be a single character. Like empty lines (as long as
> `skip_blank_lines=True`), fully commented lines are ignored by the
> parameter header but not by skiprows. For example, if `comment='#'`,
> parsing `#empty\na,b,c\n1,2,3` with `header=0` will result in ‘a,b,c’
> being treated as the header.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas `read_csv()` function ([see documentation here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)) to read the csv-file.
In this function you can add an argument called "skiprows" and define the number of rows that should be skipped when reading the file.

Comment: I have multiple files, each have different number of rows to be skipped.