# Pandas read_csv from web URL

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read a csv-file from given URL using Python 3.

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/dwrc/search/dwFullList.csv' # error
url_2 = 'https://www.cboe.com/us/options/symboldir/equity_index_options/?download=csv
df = pd.read_csv(url) # error
df = pd.read_csv(url_2) # can download csv from url
```

When I run `df = pd.read_csv(url)` the system return:

```
File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 537, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 740, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._get_header
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

However, when I run `df = pd.read_csv(url_2)` the system can return the dataframe.
How can I solve this problem? I am using Python 3.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, let's understand about `error`. The `error` you are facing was stated below:-

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte`

- You have noticed that our `error` type is the `UnicodeDecodeError` with `0xff` Codec.

**Why this `error` occurred and how to `resolve` it?**

In our case `pd.read_csv()` module use `encoding = 'utf-8'` for `Encoding` Data. and you are facing `error` with `0xff` Codec. So, `0xff` is a number represented in the `hexadecimal numeral system (base 16)`. It's composed of two `f` numbers in `hex`. As we know, `f` in `hex` is equivalent to `1111` in the `binary numeral system`.

- **Solution**:- Use `encoding = 'utf-16'` while fetching `Data`.

---

After this scenario, you may face `Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 3` `Error` Which has been occurred due to `Separation Error` of `header` and `footer`. So, the solution for your query was given below:-

```
# Import all the important Libraries
import pandas as pd 

# Fetch 'CSV' Data Using 'URL' and store it in 'df'
url = 'https://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/dwrc/search/dwFullList.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url, encoding = 'utf-16', sep = '\t', error_bad_lines = False, skiprows = 1, skipfooter = 3, engine = 'python')

# Print a few records of df
df.head()
```

**Output of Above Cell:-**
[image: Output of Above Code]

> To Learn more about `pd.read_csv()`:- [Click Here !!!](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) 
>  To Learn more about `Encoding List`:- [Click Here !!!](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings)

As you can see we have achieved our desired `Output`. Hope this Solution helps you.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by an unexpected header. If you look at the file, the first line is some 'updated' line, which is not part of the CSV. You should thus pass `skiprows` to the `read_csv`.

```
df = pd.read_csv(url, skiprows=[1])
```

See also [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20637439/skip-rows-during-csv-import-pandas).

My initial answer assumed no header was present, but it turns out it was shifted 1 line down.

Comment: I have tried skiprows = [1] or header = Non. Both are not work and show [pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 5, saw 3]

Comment: It looks like it may actually be a .tsv file (tab seperated values), despite being marked csv. Does it work if you use `sep='\t'` as an argument?