# Pandas - IF statement while Column has specific value

Tags: excel, pandas

I'm using an excel document with 5000 rows and 37 columns to get it formatted to a level where a third part software can accept the file without any problems.

Programming in PyCharm PoorPeople Edition

The problem is simple:

```
If Column_value = "XYZ": excel.write(Custom Data if True) else: excel.write(Custom Data if Else)
```

I've been trying to solve this problem for some time now and I really can't wrap my head what am I doing wrong.

Importing the data:

```
excel = xlsxwriter.Workbook('excel_file.xlsx')
```

File is now ready for formatting, lets to this:

```
Plant_EquipmentProperty = excel.dropna(subset=['Description']) #ignore anything that doesn't have Description
```

The next stage is to remove a row if a column has a specific string in it and everything I tried so far had no results (including stack overflow ideas) which were:

1. [How to drop rows from pandas data frame that contains a particular string in a particular column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679930/how-to-drop-rows-from-pandas-data-frame-that-contains-a-particular-string-in-a-p)

The problem ~df.C.str.contains("XYZ") = does not compile and includes every single column

2. [Skip rows during csv import pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20637439/skip-rows-during-csv-import-pandas)

The problem - just doesn't work at all

3. [Deleting DataFrame row in Pandas based on column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172851/deleting-dataframe-row-in-pandas-based-on-column-value)

The problem - .line_race is not a thing anymore

4. https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/check+if+value+in+column+is+null+pandas

The Problem - it's looking for null and not specifics

etc.

I've tried a numerous things and nothing seems to be as simple as if column XYZ is equal to "ABC" get rid of it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you can try importing the excel file into a pandas dataframe where you can filter the columns.

`excel=pd.read_excel('excel_file.xlsx')`

then just simply filter it:

`filtered_df=excel[excel['Column_Name']=='XYZ']`
`filtered_df.to_excel('output.xlsx')`

Comment: Wouldn't help me as I modify Colum A based on the value of Column B as an example

Comment: then try a list comprehension?
`new_col=[i if excel['Column B'][i]=='XYZ' else none for i in range(len(excel))]`
`excel['Column A']=new_col`