# Add empty header for some columns in dataframe or csv

Tags: python, dataframe, export-to-csv

I am trying to add some data above the headers in a csv file, but it has to have the last 3 columns new header empty.

My csv looks like this:

[image: example]

I have tried to create a new csv with the specific data as header and merge them with cmd but the result is having 1 extra row between them:

[image: added with cmd]

Now if I load the new csv into a DataFrame, it will read it like this:

[image: read new csv]

If I want to save the new DataFrame to csv, it will save only the columns that have info in the new header, so without the first 3 columns.

The only thing that somehow worked was to save as xlsx, open it as DataFrame and

```py
df  = pd.read_excel(file, names = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5', 'x6', 'x7', 'x8', '', '', ''])
```

but I guess it can't have the same names multiple times because the 10th column will be 0.1 and the last one 0.2

[image: last try]

Running out of ideas.
Also, the final file should be saved as csv.

Comment: Are you potentially looking to [Skip rows during csv import pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20637439/skip-rows-during-csv-import-pandas)?

Comment: Even if it has one empty row after, when read by python the row isn't there and the headers are moved to right by 3 cells

Comment: better in question (not in comments) create minimal working code with example data (in code) so we could copy and run it - to see problem and test some solutions.